# Reutilizar ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando reutilizar `ajax` para que sea mas movible en mi proyecto.
Lo coloque de la siguiente forma esperando una respuesta pero no.

```
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {params},
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
   });
}
```

Lo manda llamar:

```
var result = _ajax(null,'http://','GET');
console.log(result);
```

consola:

```
undefined
```

Como puedo reutilizarlo, las respuestas vienen en `JSON`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar un callback asi:

```
function _ajax(params,uri,type, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {params},
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

y para llamarla

```
var callback = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
_ajax(null,'http://','GET', callback);
```

Comment: El problema esque eso ya no es reutilizable, en el `callback` tendria que hacer if's para identificar a donde va ir cada información que regresa. si te das cuenta yo use un `var result = ... ` esperando que mi respuesta llegara ahí donde la mando llama. Se puede hacer eso?

Comment: La idea de el callback es que debe de ser unico.  Cada vez que llames a la funcion `_ajax` va a usar un callback diferente dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer con la variable `data`

Comment: El `response` va inscrustada a elementos es lo que te decia, tendria que identifica en el `callback` a que elementos debe irse y es lo que no quiero.

Comment: Cada vez que llames la funcion, ya sabes cual es la uri, por lo tanto ya sabes la respuesta, entonces crearias varias funciones callback y el contenido de ellas es donde incrustas los elementos.

Answer (score 8):

El "***problema***" tu solicitud es asincrona y como lo planteas no puedes trabajarlo.

```js
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
return $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: type,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("satisfactorio")
        return data;
    }});
}
let data = _ajax("" ,"https://swapi.co/api/people/1" ,"GET")
console.log("resultado" , data.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> En el ejemplo observaras que siempre se va a mostrar primero
>   `resultado` y luego `satisfactorio`,esto se conoce como funcion
>   asincrona valga la redundancia

**¿Existe alguna solucion?**

Si las enumero a continuacion:

1. **[Callbacks](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169300/28035)**: es la mas comun , pero cuando son anidadas puede darte problemas de comprension de codigo.

> Puedes ver la pregunta en el sitio [¿Que es un
>   "Callback"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96218/qu%c3%a9-es-un-callback)

2. **[Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)**: Para mi la mas valida, y soporta todos los navegadores decentes

> Te dejo un enlace por si quieres saber [mas sobre Promesas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%C3%A9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript)

```js
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {params},
        success: function(data){
            resolve(data);
        },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        reject("Status: " + textStatus); 
    }    
        
    });
    })
}
_ajax("" ,"https://swapi.co/api/people/1" ,"GET")
 .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3. **[Async/Await](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-definitions) :** Es una promesa pero mas elegante implementado por EcmaScript7, y aun no es compatible en algunos navegadores

```js
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {params},
        success: function(data){
            resolve(data);
        },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        reject("Status: " + textStatus); 
    }  
        
    });
    })
}
async function buscar(){
console.log(1)
let traeme = await _ajax("" ,"https://swapi.co/api/people/1" ,"GET")
console.log(traeme)
}
buscar()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
return $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: type,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(data){
        return data;
    }});}
```

el return y params solo manda un object :)

Comment: modifique mi pregunta quitando el return que se me fue antes de $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

La función ajax de `JQuery` realiza la petición de manera `asíncrona`: algo así como en segundo plano.

En versiones anteriores el `JQuery` permitía hacer una petición `sincronica` lo que permitía que crees una función que retorne los datos devueltos por la petición indicando la propiedad `async:false`, pero por la experiencia de usuario se quedó obsoleta esa funcionalidad.

Lo puedes intentar con una versión anterior del jQuery que soporte dicha funcionalidad, pero no es recomendable.

```
function _ajax(params,uri,type){
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: type,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {params},
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
   });
}
```

Lo que se hace por ahora para reutilizar es lo que te respondio @alanfcm la utilización de callback.

Comment: blasito te comento que ya el async ya esta deprecado http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , antes los navegadores habilitaban esa opcion; ahora siempe van a ser asincrona las peticiones, solo funciona para Internet Explorer

Comment: JackNavaRow. Creo que eso mismo comenté en la respuesta. Sólo era a modo de explicarle como funciona la petición y que antes se podía usar el async y que ahora debe usar otro método para reutilizar su petición.