# Esperar a que un for each con peticiones ajax termine para continuar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, array

estoy haciendo `forEach` en un `array` pero este bucle tiene dentro una petición ajax por cada repetición y necesito esperar hasta que todos los ajax estén listos para poder continuar a ordernar el array que se va llenando con estas peticiones, este es mi código.

```
var getTables = (scoreQ, scoreE) => {

    var arr = [];

    Object.keys(scoreQ).forEach(key => {
        var range;
        var scoreDivide = scoreE[key] / 3;
        if (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) < parseFloat(scoreDivide)) {
            range = "bajo";
        } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2))) {
            range = "medio";
        } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 3))) {
            range = "alto";
        }

        //console.log(key, range, scoreQ[key], scoreE[key])

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "php/resQuery/tables.php",
            data: {
                valuebook: key,
                range
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: response => {
                var doc = response;
                arr.push(`<tr> <td>${doc.table.valuebook.replace(/_/gi, " ")}</td> <td>${parseFloat(scoreQ[key]).toFixed(1)}</td> <td>${doc.table.rangeT}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptionp}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptions}</td> </tr>`);
            }
        });
    })

    arr.sort()
    arr.forEach(element =>{
        console.log(element);
    })

    }
```

¿cómo puedo hacer esperar el segundo forEach hasta que el primero termine de hacer todas las peticiones?

intenté poner una promesa tipo `done` y `then` después del primero pero no funcionó

Comment: Puedes setear la opción async:false en tu llamada ajax. De esta forma, se debe completar la llamada para poder continuar con la ejecución del resto del código.

Comment: cual es la razón del que quieras esperar a que llegue la la petición anterior? es solo para que tenga el mismo orden en el arreglo arr?

Comment: @LPZadkiel Sí así es, entonces omitiría el sort()

Comment: el problema con `async false` es que detiene tu código y tu página por completo, ya no podrías interactuar con ella mientras espera a que se terminen las ejecuciones ajax, te publicaré una respuesta diferente

Comment: con un async await lo puedes hacer te invito a [leer esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169324/28035)

Comment: @EmilianoPamont edite mi respuesta puedes revisarla a ver si te sirve y me comentas

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un contador y un `setInterval` que chequee hasta que el contador sea igual a la longitud de tu primer array.  Algo asi:

```
var getTables = (scoreQ, scoreE) => {

var arr = [];
var cont = Object.keys(scoreQ).length;
var i = 0;
Object.keys(scoreQ).forEach(key => {
    var range;
    var scoreDivide = scoreE[key] / 3;
    if (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) < parseFloat(scoreDivide)) {
        range = "bajo";
    } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2))) {
        range = "medio";
    } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 3))) {
        range = "alto";
    }

    //console.log(key, range, scoreQ[key], scoreE[key])

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "php/resQuery/tables.php",
        data: {
            valuebook: key,
            range
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: response => {
            i++;
            var doc = response;
            arr.push(`<tr> <td>${doc.table.valuebook.replace(/_/gi, " ")}</td> <td>${parseFloat(scoreQ[key]).toFixed(1)}</td> <td>${doc.table.rangeT}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptionp}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptions}</td> </tr>`);
        }
    });
})
var inter = setInterval(function(){ 
  if (i == cont) {
    arr.sort()
    arr.forEach(element =>{
      console.log(element);
    }) }, 1000);
    clearInterval(inter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es que se guarde en el arreglo `arr` en el mismo orden en el que ejecutas los ajax entonces puedes utilizar los indices del `forEach`

```
var getTables = (scoreQ, scoreE) => {

var arr = [];

// función sincrona para lectura de array
var SyncArray = (array, index) => {

}

var ArraydeAjaxs = [];

Object.keys(scoreQ).forEach((key, index) => {
    var range;
    var scoreDivide = scoreE[key] / 3;
    if (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) < parseFloat(scoreDivide)) {
        range = "bajo";
    } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2))) {
        range = "medio";
    } else if ((parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) >= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 2)) && (parseFloat(scoreQ[key]) <= parseFloat(scoreDivide * 3))) {
        range = "alto";
    }

    //console.log(key, range, scoreQ[key], scoreE[key])

    ArraydeAjaxs.push(
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "php/resQuery/tables.php",
        data: {
            valuebook: key,
            range
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: response => {
            var doc = response;
            arr[index] = `<tr> <td>${doc.table.valuebook.replace(/_/gi, " ")}</td> <td>${parseFloat(scoreQ[key]).toFixed(1)}</td> <td>${doc.table.rangeT}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptionp}</td> <td>${doc.table.descriptions}</td> </tr>`;
        }
    });
})
    )

$.when(...ArraydeAjaxs).done(() =>{

    arr.forEach(element =>{
        console.log(element);
    })
});

}
```

Comment: Pero aún así, se irán guardando cómo vayan llegando y el segundo `forEach` se ejecuta al cargar, de todos modos no espera a que halla valores en el `array` cuando se ejecuta el `forEach` simplemente está vacío, aunque usar`async:false` detendrá la ejecución, ordena tal cual y me parece que puedo solucionarlo poniendo una pantalla de carga.

Comment: claro no consideré el segundo forEach pero resulta que al parecer si debes esperar a que terminen para hacer algo con ese arr en ese caso hay que modificar un poco el código, editaré mi respuesta para darte una opción a este problema

Comment: @EmilianoPamont edición de respuesta para que esperen a todas las llamadas ajax y en orden en que se generan las llamadas ajax

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es enmascaran las llamadas a ajax con promesas y llamar a Promise.all, que ejecutara el callback hasta que todas estén terminadas, de esta forma no vuelves las llamas ajax bloqueantes para el usuario. 
Un ejemplo seria:

```
function getTables(scoreQ, scoreE){
  var promises = [];
  Object.keys(scoreQ).forEach(key => {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // las promesas enmascaran los datos asíncronos que necesitamos
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
        dataType: "json",
        success: resolve, //termino de promesa
        error: reject //si ocurre algún error.
      });
    });
    promises.push(promise);
  })

  Promise.all(promises).then((arr) => {
    arr.sort()
    arr.forEach(element =>{
      //aquí se puede insertar ya en el dom
      // element es lo que recibes con cada llamada ajax...
      console.log(element);
    })
  });
}

getTables({a:1, b:2});
```

Modifique el código inicial para que se pueda ver su funcionamiento al interactuar con otra API. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/uriel_tzel/pen/MqXrZY).

Answer (score 1):

Cree un pequeño código para que te puedas guiar. Lo primero que hice fue crear una variable **item** donde almaceno mi **array**, luego paso ese array como argumento a la función **procesarArray** donde si te fijas es una función **async** y dentro esta un **for** en vez de un **forEach**, el **for** llama a un función **async** llamada **promesa** el cual es una especie de manejador de promesas y el a su vez llama a un función **ajax** donde colocarías tu **ajax** y el retornaria la respuesta a **promesa** y el a su vez a **procesarArray**. En **procesarArray** una vez recibida la respuesta puedes evaluar si se ejecuto bien el ajax o no, este es el código:

```js
var items = [{item: 1, desc: "item1"}, {item: 2, desc: "item2"}, {item: 3, desc: "item3"}];

const ajax = (item) => {
  
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(resolve(item.desc),2000)
  );
  
}

const promesa = async(item) => {
  
  console.log("Llamando al ajax")
  let respuesta = await ajax(item);
  console.log("Ajax respondio = "+respuesta);
  return respuesta;
  
}

const procesarArray = async (items) => {

  for(const item of items){
    let respuesta = await promesa(item)
    console.log(respuesta);
  }
  
  console.log("listo");
  
}

procesarArray(items);
```