# ¿Porque mi Array que traigo de la BD no se muestra como uno estático?

Tags: javascript, html, array

estoy tratando de recorrer un array desde la BD con un bucle **for** pero no lo hace, aparece "**undefined**", y si hago el mismo array pero estático si lo muestra.
Adjunto los codigos acá

```
markersBarranquillaActives = [];
markerBarranquillaInActives = [];
$.get(ruta, function(response)
{
    for (var i in response['online'])
    {
        names = response['online'][i]['name'] +' '+ response['online'][i]['last_name'];
        lat = response['online'][i]['latitude'];
        lng = response['online'][i]['length'];
        markersBarranquillaActives.push([names, parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)]);
    }
});
```

Cuando voy a acceder a los valores con este bucle aparece "**undefined**":

```
for( i = 0; i < markersBarranquillaActives.length; i++ ){
    console.log(markersBarranquillaActives[i][1]);
}
```

Cuando pruebo con un codigo estático si funciona :

```
var markersBarranquillaActivess = [
    ['Asesor1', 10, 815154053],
    ['Asesor2', 11, 821784318],
    ['Asesor3', 11, 82531632],
]
```

Hice la comparacion entre los dos y esto fue el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El array que repite 3 veces el **[Array(3)]** es el estatico, el que no muestra nada es el de la BD.
Agradezco su ayuda

EDIT: el problema con ese array es que no me toma la longitud del mismo, al intentar obtener su longitud con **"length"** muestra *"0"*

Comment: Que pasa si haces la comparacion dentro del `$.get`

Comment: Pues no puedo hacerlo dentro ya que necesito esos datos fuera de la funcion para ser utilizado en otras funciones, cosa que ya logre obtener los datos fuera de ella pero igual no puedo obtener la longitud del array.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416192/como-obtengo-el-valor-de-una-variable-por-fuera-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-que-utiliza-aja) para saber porqué no puedes obtener el arreglo fuera de la petición.